# Why is my selected value showing up twice in a dropdownlist (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i have an asp.net mvc view with the following code to show a dropdown list:

```
 <% = Html.DropDownList("filter", Model.MyList, Model.MyDefaultValue, new { @id = "filter", @class = "complete" })%>
```

**Model.MyList** is a **List** with my items and one blank one at top and **Model.MYDefaultValue** is a string.

When i run this it looks like it works but i get my default listed twice

so lets say my list is:

**Ford

Toyota

Chevy**

and my Default is **Toyota**

when i click on the drop down i get:

**Toyota**

**Ford**
**Toyota**
**Chevy**

you see Toyota was added as the first item and as the 4th item.

Comment: Just a guess: 'default' is the first value. Not the SELECTED value. (so, I assume you are actually setting the first value and that there is perhaps a separate SELECTED attribute that can be set in the control)

Comment: @DA - you are correct . . why put your response in a comment versus an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Html.DropDownList()` method accepts an **optionLabel** string parameter, the text of which is inserted at the top of the dropdown list (with an empty value). It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with which item of the list is selected.

You could create a `SelectList` using your **MyList** and specify a selected value (see [SelectList Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx)) before passing it to `Html.DropDownList()`.